# Need modification in an ssh script that's written in expect

Tags: shell, expect

Am working on a script to ssh into list of servers using expect tool. Getting below error while running it

./script

```
#!/usr/local/bin/expect -f
while /usr/bin/read hostname
do
spawn ssh user@$hostname
expect "user@$hostname's password"
send "resuidt\n"
expect "user@$hostname"
interact
done < srvlist
```

Below is my error:

```
missing operand at _@_
in expression "_@_/usr/bin/read"
    (parsing expression "/usr/bin/read")
    invoked from within
"while /usr/bin/read hostname"
    (file "./script" line 3)
```

Need help to fix this error.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing an Expect program, which is basically a Tcl program. Your `while` loop is not [Tcl syntax](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1046), but looks like a (Posix/Ksh/Bash/Zsh)-shell script.

You have to make up your mind: Write everything in Tcl, or split your application into two files: One (in shell script) as "main program", and a separate expect script, which will be called by the shell script.

Comment: How to write like that. Any example for reference could be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by "that": A Tcl-only solution, or a mixed shell/Tcl solution?

Answer (score 0):

As user1934428 indicates you are using bash-type while loop syntax.
Below is one example of how to make an expect script perform the actions you want.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/expect -f

set file hostname
set user myusername
set passwd mypassword

set f [open $file]
foreach target [split [read $f] "\n"] {
  spawn ssh $user@$target
  expect {
    timeout {send_user "Expect Timeout\n" ; exit}
    "password:"
  }
  send "$passwd\r"
  expect {
    timeout {send_user "Expect Timeout\n" ; exit}
    "$user@$target"
  }
  interact
}
close $f
```

I included timeouts in the expect sections because I've found if you do not add these safety mechanisms the expect script can proceed even without the proper responses.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use shell variables directly into the expect script then you have to pass those variables as $env(shell_variable_name) inside the expect script

example:spawn ssh $env(myusername)@$env(hostname)